# command line mtp android sync with pc

Tags: sync, windows, mtp

I'd like to be able to sync a directory on my android phone with a directory on my pc from the command line over a usb cable without installing anything on the phone.

This can be done using `adb shell ls` will give you a list of files on the phone, push will copy files from pc to phone, `pull` will copy files from phone to pc and `rm` (or `rm -rf`) will delete files (or dirs) from the phone.

However, `adb push` is slow (it takes me 5x to 10x as long to copy files to an android phone using adb as it takes to copy files to an iphone using itunes).

There are pc apps which will sync (e.g., pure sync or, for ebooks, calibre), but that's not command line. Calibre seems to include python source for an mtp driver, but it's overly complex (for me).

Is there anything better?

BTW, there are many similar questions on various stackexchange sites, but I haven't found any which answer this question.

Comment: Is there any reason why you prefer command-line over apps, given that you know adb push is slow?

Comment: I can run a command line program from another program, so I can incorporate it into something I write. Android apps all seem to work over wifi, which tends to be slower than a wired USB connection.